# Kafka Consumer throwing "OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" Error on SSL

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using [Spring-Kafka 2.7.1](https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka) in a spring boot project.

When I connect it to a SSL-configured Kafka Broker it gives a "OutofMemory" Error as below even though I have increased Heap Size multiple times to no avail.

**Log Below** :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space\
    at java.base/java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:61) ~[na:na]\
    at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:348) ~[na:na]\
    at org.apache.kafka.common.memory.MemoryPool$1.tryAllocate(MemoryPool.java:30) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar!/:na]\
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:113) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar!/:na]\
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:447) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar!/:na]\
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:397) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar!/:na]\
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:674) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar!/:na]\
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:576) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar!/:na]\
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar!/:na]\
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:563) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar!/:na]\
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:265) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar!/:na]\
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:236) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar!/:na]\
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:215) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar!/:na]\
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:245) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar!/:na]\
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:480) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar!/:na]\
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1257) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar!/:na]\
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1226) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar!/:na]\
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1206) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar!/:na]\
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1414) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.7.jar!/:2.7.7]\
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1251) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.7.jar!/:2.7.7]\
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1163) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.7.jar!/:2.7.7]\
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]\
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]\
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]\
```

My Current YAML configuration is as below:

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER
    security:
      protocol: "SSL"
  consumer:
    auto-offset-reset: earliest
producer:
  topic: TOPIC
  bootstrap-servers: KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER
consumer:
  topic: TOPIC
  bootstrap-servers: KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS
```

It works as expected when connected to a NON-SSL Kafka Broker.

I have tested all other possiblities and singled out that it's related to the SSL configuration of the client.

Comment: There are a few things that you can try: 1- run a thread dump on your application that is throwing the error, it might give exactly what is consuming too much memory; 2 - remove any code from the consumer leave it with just the connection part of it and log everything; 3 - after previous test - check whether the consumer is using any resource and not closing it (such as inputstream/outputstream); start with this and depending on the result you may have better direction

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to run into out of memory errors when trying to use *Kafka secured endpoint in a non-secure way*. (It is a known issue when wrong security protocol is used or required authentication properties are not passed; OOM error is totally unrelated but it is what it is)

In case of Kafka CLI commands, usually, a property file path is passed with the command to provide security related properties.

For example:

```
kafka-topics --command-config <String: filename>
kafka-console-producer --producer.config <String: filename>
kafka-console-consumer --consumer.config <String: filename>
```

Generally contains,

```
security.protocol=<kafka_security_protocol>
ssl.truststore.location=<ssl_truststore_filename>
ssl.truststore.password=<truststore_password>
ssl.keystore.location=<client_keystore.jks>
ssl.keystore.password=<password>
ssl.key.password=<password>
```

From the question, I assumed, both producer and consumer components are connecting to the same broker(s) and declared all the required properties to connect to secured broker under **spring.kafka** section in the following example.

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER
    security:
      protocol: "SSL"
    ssl:
      trust-store-location: "truststore.jks"
      trust-store-password: "<password>"
      key-store-location: "keystore.jks"
      key-store-password: "<password>"
      key-password: "<password>"
```

If the producer and consumer are connecting to different broker(s), these properties should be specified under **spring.kafka.producer** and **spring.kafka.consumer** sections respectively.

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER
    security:
      protocol: "SSL"
producer:
  topic: TOPIC
  bootstrap-servers: KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER
  ssl.protocol: "SSL"
  ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm: "https"
  ssl:
    keystore-location: "<keystore.jks>"
    keystore-password: "<password>"
consumer:
  topic: TOPIC
  auto-offset-reset: "earliest"
  bootstrap-servers: KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS
  ssl.protocol: "SSL"
  ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm: "https"
  ssl:
    keystore-location: "<keystore.jks>"
    keystore-password: "<password>"
```

If there is no client authentication required from the broker side, then the following is a minimal configuration example:

```
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=<kafka.client.truststore.jks>
ssl.truststore.password=<password>
```

If client authentication is required, following properties are also needs to be included.

```
ssl.keystore.location=<kafka.client.keystore.jks>
ssl.keystore.password=<password>
ssl.key.password=<password>
```

Please note that the property naming convention might differ in Spring Kafka configuration.

More details on Kafka security - [Official Doc](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_overview)

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/hotspotfaq.html  https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/vmoptions-jsp.html  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40972_01/doc.70/e40973/cnf_jvmgc.htm#autoId0  https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/g1gc.html  https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/tutorials/tutorials-1876574.html  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IsIb3BZfIAE  http://www.herongyang.com/JVM/Stack-Overflow-What-Is-JVM-Stack.html